# macos boot broken after installing 18.04

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, mac, 18.04

I installed 18.04 a few weeks ago as a third partition on my Macbook Pro, which had High Sierra and 16.04. I noticed that rather than defaulting to refind, the boot loader was Ubuntu's and had 18.04 and 16.04 as the boot options. I'm trying to boot back into my mac now, but I can't seem to get that to work. Holding down alt at startup produces a black screen with a small white cursor. Holding shift to boot into safe mode just defaults back to the Ubuntu boot loader.

Holding command+R does get me to Mac's recovery mode, though. I tried resetting PRAM, which just ended up resetting the volume so I can hear the mac boot tone. I'm not sure where to continue - this either has to do with having a third partition (which I've never had before) or with have 18.04. I've read a bunch of other threads, but the symptoms don't match mine exactly. Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: Here is my fdisk output where the 56.5 G disk should be the macos

```
Device         Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1         40    409639    409600  200M EFI System
/dev/sda2     409640 118846519 118436880 56.5G unknown
/dev/sda3  118846520 314219566 195373047 93.2G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4  314482464 489972698 175490235 83.7G Linux filesystem
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all boot devices are detached when you boot, you would need to have the boot manager re-installed.